# The field tv_sec could not be resolved

Tags: c, stat, time.h

I am trying to run the following code (a simple backup program), but from some reason, the field tv_sec could not be resolved.
I tried everything that crossed my mind - but no help.
I want to emphasize that I have read the other relevant questions in this site and also tried to add the line:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

but - again - it didn't work.

Can you help me?

Thank you all!

I decided to attach the whole program, at any cas - in order to allow you to see the whole picture, if needed. 
The code (the problematic line is under the note //<>//):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <utime.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <libgen.h>

    #define MIN(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))

    // The header of each backed-up file
    typedef struct {
        char name[100];
        char mode[8];
        char uid[8];
        char gid[8];
        char size[12];
        char mtime[12];
        char typeflag;
    } bkp_header;

    // Function declarations
    int backup(char *src, char *dest);
    int restore(char *src);
    int backup_abstract(char *src, int out_file);
    int backup_file(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file);
    int backup_dir(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file);
    int backup_symlink(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file);
    int restore_file(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file);
    int restore_dir(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file);
    int restore_symlink(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file);
    int restore_metadata(bkp_header *file_header);
    bkp_header* get_file_header(char *name, struct stat buf, char type);
    int write_header_to_file(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file, char type);

    char* backup_dir_name;

    // Main
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int result = 1;

        if (argc < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid parameters\n");
        }
        else {
            // Backup
            if (strncmp(argv[1], "-c", 2) == 0) {
                if (argc < 4) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Please insert the path you want to backup\n");
                }
                else {
                    result = backup(argv[3], argv[2]);
                }
            }
            // Restore
            else if (strncmp(argv[1], "-x", 2) == 0) {
                result = restore(argv[2]);
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operation\n");
            }
        }
        exit(result);
    }

    // Takes a 'src' path and runs a backup to the 'dest' path
    int backup(char *src, char *dest) {
        // Create the backup file
        int out_file = open(dest, O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
        if (out_file < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed opening file for writing.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Get the root backup directory
        char *src_dup = strdup(src);
        backup_dir_name = dirname(src_dup);

        // Run the backup based on the type
        int result = backup_abstract(src, out_file);
        close(out_file);
        return result;
    }

    // Backup something - a file, a folder or a symbolic link
    int backup_abstract(char *src, int out_file) {
        // Get the 'src' lstat
        struct stat buf;
        if (lstat(src, &buf) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "lstat error");
            return -1;
        }

        if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
            return backup_dir(src, buf, out_file);
        }
        else if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)) {
            return backup_file(src, buf, out_file);
        }
        #ifdef  S_ISLNK
        else if (S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode)) {
            return backup_symlink(src, buf, out_file);
        }
        #endif
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can only backup a regular file, a directory, or a symlink\n");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Backup a single file
    int backup_file(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file) {
        if (write_header_to_file(name, buf, out_file, 'r') < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Copy the file right after the header in 8K chunks
        int in_file = open(name, O_RDONLY);
        if (in_file < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed opening file for reading.");
            return -1;
        }
        char read_buf[8192];
        while (1) {
            ssize_t result = read(in_file, read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
            if (result < 0) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed reading from file.");
                return -1;
            }
            if (result == 0) {
                break; /* EOF */
            }
            if (write(out_file, read_buf, (int)result) != (int)result) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed writing to file.");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        close(in_file);
        return 0;
    }

    // Backup a directory
    int backup_dir(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file) {
        if (write_header_to_file(name, buf, out_file, 'd') < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Backup the contents of this directory
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;
        if ((dir = opendir(name)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed opening directory for reading.");
            return -1;
        }
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")) {
                char full_path[100];
                strcpy(full_path, name);
                strcat(full_path, "/");
                strcat(full_path, ent->d_name);

                if (backup_abstract(full_path, out_file) != 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
        return 0;
    }

    // Backup a symbolic link
    int backup_symlink(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file) {
        if (write_header_to_file(name, buf, out_file, 'l') < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        char *link_target = malloc(buf.st_size + 1);
        if (link_target == NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed allocating memory.");
            return -1;
        }
        ssize_t link = readlink(name, link_target, buf.st_size + 1);
        if (link < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "lstat error");
            return -1;
        }
        link_target[buf.st_size] = '\0';
        if (write(out_file, link_target, buf.st_size) != buf.st_size) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed writing to file.");
            return -1;
        }
        free(link_target);
        return 0;
    }

    // Get the backup header for a file
    bkp_header* get_file_header(char *name, struct stat buf, char type) {
        bkp_header *file_header = (bkp_header*)malloc(sizeof(bkp_header));

        int abs_path_start = strncmp(name, backup_dir_name, strlen(backup_dir_name));
        if (abs_path_start != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Warning: Failed converting backup path to relative.");
        }
        else {
            name = &name[strlen(backup_dir_name)+1];
        }

        sprintf(file_header->name, name);
        sprintf(file_header->mode, "%d", buf.st_mode);
        sprintf(file_header->uid, "%d", buf.st_uid);
        sprintf(file_header->gid, "%d", buf.st_gid);
        sprintf(file_header->size, "%d", (int)buf.st_size);
//<<PROBLEM!!!>>//
        sprintf(file_header->mtime, "%d", (int)buf.st_mtim.tv_sec); 
        file_header->typeflag = type;

        return file_header;
    }

    // Create and write the header to the output file
    int write_header_to_file(char *name, struct stat buf, int out_file, char type) {
        bkp_header *file_header = get_file_header(name, buf, type);
        if (write(out_file, file_header, sizeof(bkp_header)) != sizeof(bkp_header)) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed writing to file.");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Takes a 'src' backup file path and extracts it to the current working dir
    int restore(char *src) {
        // Read the backup file
        int bkp_file = open(src, O_RDONLY);
        if (bkp_file < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed opening backup file for reading.");
            return -1;
        }
        while (1) {
            // Read the header
            char header_buf[sizeof(bkp_header)];
            ssize_t h_result = read(bkp_file, header_buf, sizeof(header_buf));
            if (h_result < 0) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed reading from backup file.");
                return -1;
            }
            if (h_result == 0) {
                break; /* EOF */
            }
            bkp_header *file_header = header_buf;

            // Restore the file/dir/symbolic-link
            if (file_header->typeflag == 'r') {
                if (restore_file(file_header, bkp_file) < 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else if (file_header->typeflag == 'd') {
                if (restore_dir(file_header, bkp_file) < 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else if (file_header->typeflag == 'l') {
                if (restore_symlink(file_header, bkp_file) < 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring, unknown file type found.");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        close(bkp_file);
        return 0;
    }

    // Restore a single file based on the header and the raw bkp_file
    int restore_file(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file) {
        // Make sure the output file does not exist
        int out_file;
        out_file = open(file_header->name, O_RDONLY);
        if (out_file != -1) {
            close(out_file);
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring, file %s already exists.", file_header->name);
            return -1;
        }

        // Create and open it for writing
        out_file = open(file_header->name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
        if (out_file < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed opening backed-up file path for writing.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Restore the file's meta data
        if (restore_metadata(file_header) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring backed-up file meta data.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Read the content of the file in 8K chunks, and write them to disk
        int file_size = atoi(file_header->size);
        while (file_size) {
            // Read a chunk from the backup file
            char file_buf[8192];
            ssize_t f_result = read(bkp_file, file_buf, MIN(sizeof(file_buf), file_size));
            if (f_result < 0) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed reading from backup file.");
                return -1;
            }
            if (f_result == 0) {
                break; /* EOF */
            }

            // Write this chunk to the disc
            if (write(out_file, file_buf, (int)f_result) != (int)f_result) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Failed writing file to disc.");
                return -1;
            }
            file_size -= f_result;
        }
        close(out_file);
        return 0;
    }

    // Restore a directory based on the header and the raw bkp_file
    int restore_dir(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file) {
        // Create this folder on the disc
        if (mkdir(file_header->name, atoi(file_header->mode)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed creating directory.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Restore the directory's meta data
        if (restore_metadata(file_header) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring backed-up directory's meta data.");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Restore a symbolic link (not the target file) based on the header and the raw bkp_file
    int restore_symlink(bkp_header *file_header, int bkp_file) {
        // Make sure the output file does not exist
        int out_file;
        out_file = open(file_header->name, O_RDONLY);
        if (out_file != -1) {
            close(out_file);
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring, symlink %s already exists.", file_header->name);
            return -1;
        }

        int path_size = atoi(file_header->size);
        char *file_buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*path_size);
        if (file_buf == NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed allocating memory.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Read the content of the file, get the link target
        ssize_t f_result = read(bkp_file, file_buf, path_size);
        if (f_result < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed reading from backup file.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Create this symbolic link on the disc
        if (symlink(file_buf, file_header->name) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed creating symlink.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Restore the link's meta data
        if (restore_metadata(file_header) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed restoring backed-up link meta data.");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    // Set the original UID, GID, permissions and modification time
    int restore_metadata(bkp_header *file_header) {
        if (lchown(file_header->name, atoi(file_header->uid), atoi(file_header->gid)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "chown error");
            return -1;
        }
        if (file_header->typeflag != 'l') {
            // No lchmod in my glibc, not restoring mode for symlinks
            if (chmod(file_header->name, atoi(file_header->mode)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stdout, "chmod error");
                return -1;
            }
            struct utimbuf ubuf;
            ubuf.modtime = atoi(file_header->mtime);
            if (utime(file_header->name, &ubuf) != 0) {
                fprintf(stdout, "utime error");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than describe the error message "the field tv_sec could not be resolved.", post the error message.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the error.

Comment: Is this on a recent Linux distro, or something else?

Comment: It could have been fair to extract interesting part of your code to provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` has `struct stat` type in which there exists a `st_mtime` field of type `time_t`. `time_t` is usually defined as an arithmetic type not a structured one, it has then no field.